# How to have Power bi live connection with servers in different domain?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssas-tabular, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I am working with Power Bi report server and want to connect SSAS tabular model in Live connection mode. The problem is my servers are not in the same domain and I am not able to connect to Tabular with this domain windows credential. Is there any way to set the different domain windows credential in power bi RS ? Or if there is any other solution please advise

Comment: have you tried using <domainname>\<username>?

Comment: where can I enter credential when I connect to SSAS?

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem with NTLM Solution ....
see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/authentication-methodologies-supported-by-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions